# Update column B to column A, but only If table A is empty

Tags: mysql

I need to move the values in the column name

> options_2

into the column name

> options_1

But **only** on the condition when options_1 is  **empty**. (Point A in the image.)
If options_1 is not empty ( Point B in the image ), then nothing should happen as I do not want to overwrite the existing values.

Additionally, I would like to then clear our options_2. But this time the rule should be to only clear our options_2 if it is the exact duplicate of options_1. This would make sure that it won't delete all the option_2 values, which are valid ones further down in the database.

[image]

The structure is as follows:

database_name >> wp_cart66_products

I researched and found the command:

> update 'wp_cart66_products' set 'options_1' = 'options_2'

But this has no conditional rules, and would transfer and overwrite valid values as well, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update wp_cart66_products
set options_1 = options_2,
    options_2 = ''
where options_1 IS NULL or options_1 = ''
```

Comment: perhaps followed by a second update `... set options_2=null where options_1=options_2` to fulfil the second part of the question?

Comment: @wwkudu:  that gets into non-atomic operations.  Instead, I have updated the answer to immediately update the other field.  Since those updates are in an implicit transaction, it should not be possible to drop the ball on the update.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need. Note that is goes ahead and clears `options_2` when copying the data over, as in this case options 1 & 2 would have been equal if option 2 remained unchanged.

```
UPDATE `wp_cart66_products`
SET
    `options_1` = `options_2`,
    `options_2` = ''
WHERE
    `options_1` = ''
    OR `options_1` IS NULL
```

This takes care of all your cases in Block A of your picture, but would not touch those items in Block B. This sounds like what you wanted.

You could then run a second query like this to take care of the cases where option_1 and option_2 match from the start, and you want to clear options_2.

```
UPDATE `wp_cart66_products`
SET `options_2` = ''
WHERE `options_1` = `options_2`
```

After your run these two queries you will only have two different cases for your field tuple:

- `options_1` is non-zero-length string and `options_2` is empty string
- `options_1` and `options_2` are non-matching strings of non-zero length.